# How do I open PDFs in Firefox without causing an infinite loop of blank tabs?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I have a fresh Firefox install on a Win7 PC without a dedicated PDF reader. I was under the impression that I don't need to install one because Firefox has a built-in viewer. But if I attempt to open a downloaded PDF, Firefox opens a tab and then apparently decides that it should forward the file to Firefox for opening - which opens a new tab yet again, and this sequence repeats until I close the browser or my PC runs out of RAM.

The setting for content type PDF is set to "preview in Firefox". That works for a subset of files from the 'net (I guess those with an appropriate response header) but fails for downloaded files. What do I have to do to fix this?

**Note that installing a dedicated PDF reader is *not* an acceptable solution.** This did work flawlessly without a third party plugin like acrobat or foxit etc on my old Win7 install, but I reinstalled the OS and now it's broken for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but I was having the same problem myself today, and this is still near the top of the search results I got.

This worked for me:
Go to ☰ -> Options -> Applications -> Search for the PDF type and set to "Preview in Firefox".